# Displaying issues with animation and getting feedback about it

Tags: usability, interaction-design

The app I'm building has multiple numbers of animations showcased, but some of them may have issues on displaying or playing correctly, it might be compatible with playing on web but might not be able to play correctly on iOS or android.

Does anyone know an intuitive way of letting users know that it might not be compatible with their devices, and how they can report it?

Any good examples?

Answer (score 1):

Well I can at least address your first question with the information belongs to it's implementation part, even it has considered within development phase which is out of this site's scope.

First, it's pretty easy to find out a client (targeted user here) device's operating system via a server-side programming language. So that you may understand if it's iOS, Android, or Mac/Windows. By this way basically, you may try to warn each of iOS/Android users that they may have an experience of this kind of problems first.

Then additionally, you may make them voluntarily report these kind of issues or try to use any other kind of operating systems or devices (to say web here) to be able to get a better performance.

**And also for your second question**: I think most of the sites like HackerRank already doing it today like warning their users to use Firefox or Chrome other than the rest, when they want their users to get most benefit out of their applications.

Comment: Thank you @Erhan, actually, I just want to simply want users to report a broken animation. because compatibility between android and iOS is different from these animations.

Comment: Then I'd just suggest alerting at the opening of the application like basically alerting that your platform may perform different visual animation problems depending on user's platform preferences. By doing so, you may gain a bit interest of users other than closing the entire app without reporting.